# Time series returns NaN when sliced and multiplied

Tags: pandas, time-series

Snippet:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dr = pd.date_range(start='1984-01-01', end='1984-01-10')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(len(dr)), index=dr, columns=["Values"])

df.iloc[:-5,] * df.iloc[5:,]
```

Return:

[image]

The multiplication works if I don't slice:

```
df*df
```

Return:

[image]

So my guess is that when the index does not match, Pandas will not perform any operation and simply return `NaN`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is different `DatatimeIndex` in both sliced `DataFrames`, possible solution is multiple by numpy array for prevent data alignment different indices what return `NaN`s:

```
print (df.iloc[:-5,].index)
DatetimeIndex(['1984-01-01', '1984-01-02', '1984-01-03', '1984-01-04',
               '1984-01-05'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')

print (df.iloc[5:,].index)
DatetimeIndex(['1984-01-06', '1984-01-07', '1984-01-08', '1984-01-09',
               '1984-01-10'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
```

---

```
print (df.iloc[:-5,] * df.iloc[5:,].values)
            Values
1984-01-01       0
1984-01-02       6
1984-01-03      14
1984-01-04      24
1984-01-05      36
```

Or create same index values in both sliced DataFrames:

```
print(df.iloc[5:,])
            Values
1984-01-06       5
1984-01-07       6
1984-01-08       7
1984-01-09       8
1984-01-10       9

print(df.iloc[5:,].set_index(df.index[:-5]))
            Values
1984-01-01       5
1984-01-02       6
1984-01-03       7
1984-01-04       8
1984-01-05       9

print(df.iloc[:-5,] * df.iloc[5:,].set_index(df.index[:-5]))
            Values
1984-01-01       0
1984-01-02       6
1984-01-03      14
1984-01-04      24
1984-01-05      36
```

And next approach is multiple by numpy arrays in both DataFrames and then use DataFrame constructor:

```
print(pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[:-5,].values * df.iloc[5:,].values, 
                   columns=df.columns,
                   index=df.index[:-5]))
            Values
1984-01-01       0
1984-01-02       6
1984-01-03      14
1984-01-04      24
1984-01-05      36
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael! I tried integer index instead and it is the same `NaN` result. Lessons learned!

Comment: @Cheng - yes, same problem with default index, there is also another solution possible like `print(pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[:-5,].reset_index(drop=True) * df.iloc[5:,].reset_index(drop=True)))` - create default index in each slice. But it is not possible use here, because lost DatetimeIndex.